# Clear in Java is leading to null results?

Tags: java, arrays, list

I want to exercise the "Clear" utility of java. However, when I am using clear even after adding the sublist value to the super list, the values are somehow overwritten to null. What is the reason for this behavior?

```
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        List<Integer> abc= new LinkedList<>();
        List<List<Integer>> abc2= new LinkedList<>();
        int j=2;
        while(j > 0) {
            for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
                abc.add(i);
            }
            //abc.stream().forEach(e-> System.out.println(e));
            abc2.add(abc);
            abc.clear();
            //abc= new LinkedList<>();
            j--;
        }

        abc2.stream().forEach(e-> System.out.println("," + e));
    }
}
```

Why I am getting below result:

,[],[]

instead of:

,[1, 2, 3]
,[1, 2, 3]

Comment: `abc2` contains the same list, `abc`, multiple times. `abc` is empty because you clear it.

Comment: I added it to the main list before clearing it. Shouldn't it value to retain the abc2 list?

Comment: No, the list inside `abc2` is the *same list* as `abc`. So if you clear it, it's empty.

Comment: Simply put, you're passing by reference `abc`. That's because Java passes by reference objects. So when you clear `abc`, it gets cleared from `abc2`.